# Como fazer o servidor retornar uma pagina sem a requisição do navegador

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma tela de cadastro que deve ser validada por varias regras de negocio, quando o usuário fizer o submit eu queria deixar uma pagina com uma mensagem por exemplo, "Validando, aguarde". Tentei fazer isso com delegates assíncronos, eu fiz um projeto de teste só pra testar se daria certo, a logica no servidor até funcionou, ele chamou um método que coloque um sleep na thread para simbolizar o tempo de validação e chamou o método que traz a tela de espera o problema é que a tela não aparece, apesar de ser chamada. vejam o código do controller

```
public delegate int Completo();

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //chama o metodo trabalhar que simula a espera e coloca a action ValidacaoCompleto para ser executada quando o metodo
    //Trabalhar estiver concluído
    public void Validacao()
    {
        Numero n = new Numero();
        Completo c = new Completo(n.Trabalhar);
        IAsyncResult result = c.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback (ValidacaoCompleto), null);
        TelaValidacao();
    }

    //chama a View de espera
    public ActionResult TelaValidacao()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //esse metodo chama a View de validação concluida, não chamei a View direto no metodo TelaValidacao 
    //por que o tipo de retorno do metodo que será chamdo pelo delegate assincrono não pode ser Actionresult
    public void ValidacaoCompleto(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ChamarTelaFinal();
    }

    //chama a View de validação concluida
    public ActionResult ChamarTelaFinal()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou focar no que acho ser o ponto chave de sua pergunta:

> (...) eu queria deixar uma pagina com uma mensagem por exemplo, "Validando, aguarde" (...).

Não sou especialista em MVC. Creio que se você forçar a carga de alguma página do lado do servidor, o que pode estar a acontecer é que quem fez a requisição é código do lado do servidor, e quem vai receber a resposta é o mesmo.

Se tudo o que você quer é uma tela de carga, o ideal seria fazer isso do lado do cliente. Você faz a requisição *Ajax* e ao mesmo tempo coloca alguma *gif* animada ou qualquer coisa que indique que há algum processamento ocorrendo no servidor.

Quando obtiver uma resposta da requisição Ajax, você trata a resposta e exibe um resultado de acordo.

Um pequeno trecho de **pseudo-código** para ilustrar:

No XHTML:

```
<asp:Hidden runat="server" clientIDMode="static" id="resultado" />
```

No code-behind:

```
public void Processa () {
    bool deuTudoCerto;
    /* .. SNIP .. */
    resultado.Value = deuTudoCerto.ToString();
}
```

E no Javascript (supondo que você usa jQuery):

```
var animacaoProcessamento = $("#processamento");
$.ajax({
    url: enderecoDaPaginaQueProcessaResultado
}).done(function (
    var deuTudoCerto = $("#resultado").val() === "true";
    alert(deuTudoCerto ? "Deu tudo certo!" : "Ops, falhou...");
    animacaoProcessamento.fadeOut();
));
animacaoProcessamento.fadeIn();
```

Comment: realmente, usando ajax é mais simples. No ASP.NET MVC tem o metodo ajax.beginform que envia o formulário todo via ajax, vou postar o código completo de como eu fiz.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema com o Ajax.BeginForm, onde a requisição é enviada via Ajax e eu marco o conteúdo de uma div para ser copiado para outra após a ação do submit, assim posso fazer com que o conteudo de uma div oculta seja exibido em uma div que estava vazia, e esse conteúdo pode ser um código com a menssagem de aguardando.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Validacao", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultado", LoadingElementId = "carregando" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar" />
}


<div id="carregando" style="display:none">
    <center>
        <h1><strong>Validação em andamento, aguarde...</strong></h1>
    </center>
</div>

<div id="resultado">

</div>
```